# What is NbClust method for k-means initialization?

Tags: r, k-means

In the r's NbClust package paper, there is the part

> "Often another cluster algorithm (e.g., UPGMA) is run initially to
>   determine starting points for the cluster center."

However, one might ask if the function implements any of these.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code from NbClust, you can find that *kmeans()* is called many times, with no preset centroids vector, each time with set.seed(1) called right before. This shows that the NbClust does not implement any initialization for its kmeans call. eg. (line 1425) :

```
set.seed(1)
        cl0 <- kmeans(jeu,nc-1)$cluster
```